# how should i make an object show through another

Tags: objects

im making a face thats meant to look cartoonish in style, and i want to know how to get the eyelashes to show up over the hair in renders, (and if possible, the viewport.)
[image: not photoshopped]
it looks like this

[image: poorly photoshopped]
but I want it to look like this (bad at photoshop)

how do i do that?

Comment: [This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/117085/35559) might be of interest, but only in Cycles with OSL...

Answer (score 1):

- To show an object in front of everything else in viewport:

  [image]
- To do that when rendering you need to use compositing, check this answer for that:

[How to render object in front of everything else?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196821/how-to-render-object-in-front-of-everything-else)

Comment: oh ok thank you!