Render Object in Front of Another Object?
I'm trying to achieve a cartoon electrocution effect using a rigged character, with their skeleton becoming visible while the body becomes a solid black. It's important that the skeleton doesn't get rendered in front of the entire render, only in front of the body. I attempted to achieve this by flipping the body's normals but inverted faces on the front of the model are blocking the skeleton from view. What's the best way of going about this?

Duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196821/how-to-render-object-in-front-of-everything-else. In your case if there are objects in front of the character, you'll need to set 3 layers (character+background, skeleton, and front).
